# Copy data from a row inside a data frame and put it into an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, plyr

this might seem like a really easy task, but I am a beginner in R.
The task is as simple as the title explains it.

I have a data frame and I would like to take all the text values from a row and put it into an array.

I would like to use this statement, I just do not know what to use as a function:

```
review = daply(.data = mydata[1,], .variables = mydata$names , .fun = ??? )
```

Is there a function to copy data or getText or is there an easier way ?

My end goal is to take each row in the data frame and put it in an array, since I need to use an array for different of data analysis functions from a package.

I know it is not good to write loops for this, so is there any function in the **plyr** package in R that would accomplish the end goal mentioned above ?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
code:

```
result <- apply(mydata[1,], 1, function(x) { classify_emotion(x, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0) })
 > emotion = result[,7]
 Error in result[, 7] : subscript out of bounds
 > emotion = result[,6]
 Error in result[, 6] : subscript out of bounds
 > emotion = result[7,] 
 > emotion[is.na(emotion)] = "unknown"
 > class_pol = apply(mydata[1,], 1, function(x) {classify_polarity(x, algorithm="bayes") })
 > polarity = class_pol[,4]
 Error in class_pol[, 4] : subscript out of bounds
 > polarity = class_pol[4,]
 > resu <- apply(mydata, 1, function(x) {data.frame(text=x, emotion=emotion,polarity=polarity, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) })
 > resu = within(resu ,emotion <- factor(emotion, levels=names(sort(table(emotion), decreasing=TRUE))))
 >  write.xlsx(resu, "C:/Users/Norbert/Desktop/resu.xlsx")
```

I am trying to replicate this : https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/sentiment/sentiment
@Tim Biegeleisen Look at the website. Can you see a mistake ?

Comment: What do you plan to do with these arrays?  You may be able to subset your data frame and use it directly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to pass the array as a parameter to a few functions from a package

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would be okay with subsetting the data frame as long as I can have arrays by each row.... because the data frame contains thousand of data and I want to analyze the data row by row for clear results... each row is completely different from the other rows. could you suggest a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply()` function in row mode on your data frame.  You can pass each row to the function `classify_emotion` like this:

```
result <- data.frame(apply(mydata, 1, function(x) {
                               y <- classify_emotion(x, "bayes", 1.0)
                               return(y)
                           }))
```

Comment: This is how the statement looks like... but it did not work : `result <- apply(mydata, 1, function(x) { classify_emotion(x, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0) })`

Comment: It almost worked. Really close. I will try again, I have to see where my mistake is. Thanks for your help. I will post my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80352/discussion-between-uther-pendragon-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: You need to `data.frame` the matrix output from `apply()`.  Then all should be happy.

Comment: I started coding in R 2 weeks ago. Do you mean something like this: ` result <- data.frame(apply(mydata[1,], 1, function(x) { classify_emotion(x, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0) }))
`

Comment: `result <- data.frame(apply(mydata[1,], 1, function(x) { classify_emotion(x, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0) }))`

Comment: Thanks, I got the right data, now I just have to apply the algorithms on it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your help. I will manipulate the data and I will do as you sad.

Comment: Your solution worked, but the output is weird after the algorithm is applied. That is not your fault, since your solution is correct, but the algorithm is not designed to use a data.frame with to statements. Just if you want, would you be kind enough to suggest a statement which will transform each row of the data.frame into an array...something like a `daply` statement...I do not know how to do it

Comment: I am thinking about a statement like `review = daply(.data = mydata[1,], .variables = mydata$names , .fun = ??? )`

Comment: You really want to be using one of the `apply()` functions here.  Play around with it until you get the exact result you want.  I was unable to install the `sentiment` package locally which limited the amount of help I could give you.